# how to set Progress bar

Tags: android

```
public class circularlistparsing extends ActivityGroup {

public int currentPage = 1;
public ListView lisView1;
static final String KEY_ITEM = "docdetails";
static final String KEY_ITEM2 = "info";
static final String KEY_NAME1 = "";
static final String KEY_NAME = "heading";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public Button btnNext;
public Button btnPre;
public static String url = "http://dev.taxmann.com/TaxmannService/TaxmannService.asmx/GetCircularList";
TextView txtreord;
TextView totalpage;
TextView pagenumber;
ProgressDialog dialog;
TextView title;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txtreord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recored);
    totalpage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalpage);
    pagenumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagenumber);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    title.setText("Cirrcular");
    // listView1
    lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Next
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    // Perform action on click
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPage = currentPage + 1;

            // new YourTask().execute();
            ShowData();
            pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage + "]");
        }
    });

    // Previous
    btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
    // Perform action on click
    btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPage = currentPage - 1;

            // new YourTask().execute();
            ShowData();
            pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage + "]");
        }
    });


    ShowData();
 }

public void ShowData() {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM2);

    int displayPerPage = 10; // Per Page
    int TotalRows = nl.getLength();

    txtreord.setText(TotalRows + "Records|"); // number of records

    int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);
    int TotalPage = 0;
    if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
        TotalPage = 1;
    } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
        TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
    } else {
        TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
        TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
    }

    totalpage.setText("Page[" + TotalPage);

    int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
    if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
        indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
    }

    // Disabled Button Next
    if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
        btnNext.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        btnNext.setEnabled(true);
    }

    // Disabled Button Previos
    if (currentPage <= 1) {
        btnPre.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        btnPre.setEnabled(true);
    }

    // Load Data from Index
    int RowID = 1;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    // RowID
    if (currentPage > 1) {
        RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
    }

    for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        Element e2 = (Element) n2.item(i);

        String date = e2.getAttribute(KEY_DATE);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));

        map.put(KEY_DATE, date);



        String mytime = date;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
        Date myDate = null;
        try {
            myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

        } catch (ParseException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException t) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

        // System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrr"+finalDate);

        String Heading = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);

        int a = Heading.indexOf("|");
        String beforeSubString = Heading.substring(0, a);
        String afterSubString = Heading.substring(a, Heading.length())
                .replace("|", "") + "[" + finalDate + "]";
        // String
        // final1="<b>"+beforeSubString+"<b>"+"|"+afterSubString.replace("|",
        // "|\n")
        // .replace("|", "");
        // String k=Html.fromHtml(final1).toString();
        //
        // Html.fromHtml(final1);

        map.put(KEY_NAME, beforeSubString);
        map.put(KEY_NAME1, afterSubString);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);

        RowID = RowID + 1;

    }

    SimpleAdapter sAdap;
    sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(circularlistparsing.this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { "RowID", KEY_NAME1, KEY_NAME }, new int[] {
                    R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName, R.id.textView1 });
    lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

    lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(circularlistparsing.this, detail.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            // i.putExtra("product", product);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
}
```

This is my source code This Activity public class circularlistparsing extends ActivityGroup 
This is my Activity this Actvity is loading onButton click of another class i want to set progress bar for loading data please tell me how to Implement this i did try much but not able to Display Progress bar I have use asynk task then also not able to display .

Comment: you want to show `Progress bar` or `Progress dialog` ? It is possible using `Async Task` post your `YourTask()` code.

Answer (score 1):

Change you code with this code.

```
public int currentPage = 1;
public ListView lisView1;
static final String KEY_ITEM = "docdetails";
static final String KEY_NAME = "heading";
public Button btnNext;
public Button btnPre;
int TotalPage = 0;
int ERROR_CODE;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
public static String url = "paste your URL";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // listView1
    lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Next
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    // Previous
    btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
    // Perform action on click
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPage = currentPage + 1;
            new Data().execute();
        }
    });

    // Perform action on click
    btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPage = currentPage - 1;
            new Data().execute();
        }
    });

    new Data().execute();
}

private class Data extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, "",
                "Loading...");

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // do hard work here
        ShowData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        progress.dismiss();
        if (ERROR_CODE == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, "No Xml found.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (ERROR_CODE == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, "No doc found.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Disabled Button Next
            if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
            }

            // Disabled Button Previos
            if (currentPage <= 1) {
                btnPre.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                btnPre.setEnabled(true);
            }

            SimpleAdapter sAdap;
            sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this,
                    menuItems, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "RowID",
                            KEY_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.ColRowID,
                            R.id.ColName });
            lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);
        }
    }
}

public void ShowData() {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML
    if (xml != null) {
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        if (doc != null) {
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

            int displayPerPage = 5; // Per Page
            int TotalRows = nl.getLength();
            int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);

            if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
                TotalPage = 1;
            } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
                TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
            } else {
                TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
                TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
            }
            int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
            if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
                indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
            }

            // Load Data from Index
            int RowID = 1;
            menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            // RowID
            if (currentPage > 1) {
                RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
            }

            for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);

                RowID = RowID + 1;
            }
        }
        ERROR_CODE = 2;
    }
    ERROR_CODE = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

    RelativeLayout fv = new RelativeLayout(this);
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this);
    fv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    fv.addView(pb);
    setContentView(fv); 
}
```

This work fine with me..

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
txtreord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recored);
totalpage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalpage);
pagenumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagenumber);
title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

title.setText("Cirrcular");
// listView1
lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

// Next
btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
// Perform action on click
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        currentPage = currentPage + 1;

        // new YourTask().execute();
        ShowData();
        pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage + "]");
    }
});

// Previous
btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
// Perform action on click
btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        currentPage = currentPage - 1;

        // new YourTask().execute();
        ShowData();
        pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage + "]");
      }
   });

   new NflAsyncTask().execute();

   }
}       
public class NflAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activityname.this,
            "Please wait", "Loading Data ...", true);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM2);

        int displayPerPage = 10; // Per Page
        int TotalRows = nl.getLength();

        txtreord.setText(TotalRows + "Records|"); // number of records

        int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);
        int TotalPage = 0;
        if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
            TotalPage = 1;
        } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
        } else {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
            TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
        }

        totalpage.setText("Page[" + TotalPage);

        int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
        if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
            indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
        }

        // Disabled Button Next
        if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Disabled Button Previos
        if (currentPage <= 1) {
            btnPre.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPre.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Load Data from Index
        int RowID = 1;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        // RowID
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            Element e2 = (Element) n2.item(i);

            String date = e2.getAttribute(KEY_DATE);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));

            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);

            String mytime = date;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
            Date myDate = null;
            try {
                myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

            } catch (ParseException t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.text.ParseException t) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

            // System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrr"+finalDate);

            String Heading = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);

            int a = Heading.indexOf("|");
            String beforeSubString = Heading.substring(0, a);
            String afterSubString = Heading.substring(a, Heading.length())
                    .replace("|", "") + "[" + finalDate + "]";
            // String
            // final1="<b>"+beforeSubString+"<b>"+"|"+afterSubString.replace("|",
            // "|\n")
            // .replace("|", "");
            // String k=Html.fromHtml(final1).toString();
            //
            // Html.fromHtml(final1);

            map.put(KEY_NAME, beforeSubString);
            map.put(KEY_NAME1, afterSubString);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
            RowID = RowID + 1;
        }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


    progressDialog.dismiss();
    SimpleAdapter sAdap;
    sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(circularlistparsing.this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { "RowID", KEY_NAME1, KEY_NAME }, new int[] {
                    R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName, R.id.textView1 });
    lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);
}
}
}
```

Comment: make this NflAsyncTask class or You can copy past this and call this class with   new NflAsyncTask().execute();

Comment: We have to remove ShowData() in place that we have to call new NflAsyncTask().execute();?

Comment: yes... in NflAsyncTask class have doInBackground method it this method we call your ShowData()

Comment: fatal exception asynctask #1 Logcat Error is coming

Comment: do this way ok with same class put this NflAsyncTask  but out of oncreate